# Do not save changes for Inverse Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to ignore InverseProperty on saving but it needs to work on fetching. Is it possible to configure preferably with data annotations?

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020660/why-does-ef-code-first-inverseproperty-attribute-fail-to-work-when-used-with